# How to unbold my tcsh prompt (my tcsh prompt is stuck bold)?

Tags: prompt, csh

Unlike most searches I did on this question, I want my prompt to **not** be bold. But I can't stop it.

Here is how I set my prompt.

```csh
set green     = "%{\033[01;32m%}"
set white     = "%{\033[37m%}"
set unbold    = "%{\033[0m%}"
set end       = "%{\033[m%}"
set prompt="${unbold}${green}\%${white} ${end}"
```

I just added the unbold in an effort to stop the bolding. It started when I noticed a bug in the font I am using (SourceCodePro, and perhaps a bug KiTTY) that chops off a few pixels from the '1' character. But only when bolded. I don't know why, but it's really off-putting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `green` escape sequence is setting bold with the `;1`. (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Examples)):

> CSI 32 m — This makes text green. The green may be a dark, dull green, so you may wish to enable Bold with the sequence CSI 1 m which would make it bright green, or combined as CSI 32 ; 1 m. Some implementations use the Bold state to make the character Bright.

That means in some implementations you cannot have bright green and not bold. Just remove the `;1` and you should be ok:

```
set green     = "%{\033[32m%}"
```

Or, if you want the bright green, turn off the bold at the prompt with:

```
set prompt="${green}${unbold}\%${white} ${end}"
```

Notice that the `green` and `unbold` are swapped.

Comment: Nailed it! I copy/pasted my list of color codes from <somewhere-on-web> and didn't realize I had picked up those modifiers. Thanks Eduardo!